# Why explicitly .open() a connection in MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoskin

I have this connection set:

```
var db = mongo.db('mongodb://localhost/inline_dev', {native_parser:true});
```

I then open a connection, and fetch some document...

```
db.open(function(err, db)
db.collection('test').find().toArray(function(err, dbDocs) {
  if (!err) {
    console.log(dbDocs)
    }
  });
```

... but this seems to work as well, without the explicit `.open()`:

```
db.collection('test').find().toArray(function(err, dbDocs) {
  if (!err) {
    console.log(dbDocs)
    }
  });
```

**Q)** Why can/should I explicitly `open()` the connection, given that it seems like the connection is opened as soon as I try to query a collection anyway?

Actually, it seems like the connection is opened as soon as I point my browser to the URL of the app (at least according to the mongod log).

Comment: And according to these docs. http://webapplog.com/tutorial-node-js-and-mongodb-json-rest-api-server-with-mongoskin-and-express-js/

Comment: @JohnBarça I don't get it. Anyhow, to the poster, just a friendly reminder to review and either accept your previous answers or otherwise leave comments to those who have answered explaining why the answer does not suit. There seems to be quite a lot of unaccepted answers there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mongoskin as much like other implementations do some "funny stuff" to cover up an initial connection which should actually be done in a callback. So really you should be waiting for the "open" to complete, but the actual process is "hidden" by holding the other operations until the connection is made.

A good way to illustrate it to inspect the Object from each in code:

```js
var mongo = require('mongoskin');
var db = mongo.db("mongodb://localhost/test");

console.log( "Before" );
console.log( db );
db.open(function(err,conn) {
  console.log( "After" );
  console.log( conn );
  console.log( "And DB:" );
  console.log( db );
});
```

But to your code in general it should not make a difference.